# Visual C++: Serial Port Data Received Event - ReceivedByteThreshold issue

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

We are working with serial port byte processing in Visual Studio 2013 .NET Framework 4.5. We are experiencing problems with varying incoming packet size.  When we try to adjust the ReceivedByteThreshold to the corresponding packet size, data Received event was triggered multiple times when the threshold was set lower than the incoming packet size and does not activate when the threshold is larger than the packet size. We have tried couple different ways to address this issue but none of them seems to work perfectly.

```
    private: System::Void serialPort1_DataReceived(System::Object^  sender, System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^  e)
         {


             array<uint8_t>^ CS = gcnew array<uint8_t>(2);
             //Check InvokeRequired to prevent cross threading problem 
             if (textBox3->InvokeRequired) {
                 //Invoke delegate
                 textBox3->Invoke(
                     gcnew System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this, &MyForm::serialPort1_DataReceived),
                     gcnew array<System::Object^> { sender, e }
                 );
             }

             else
             {

                 //ASCII -> HEX Conversion
                 int numbytes = serialPort1->BytesToRead;
                 array<Byte>^ encodedBytes = gcnew array<Byte>(500);

                 serialPort1->Read(encodedBytes, 0, numbytes);

             }
         }
```

Code above works only if the threshold is set to the exact packet size. 
Since we have some knowledge of the incoming data length, we have used a button click event to change the threshold based on the outgoing buffer but the data is still not reading in correctly. Readexisting() works perfect but when we scan any 8-bit ASCII character it shows up as "?" for ex. 0xff.

I am wondering if anyone has run into the same issue, or have any solution to this threshold issue.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Yoshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, relying on ReceivedThreshold produces *very* brittle code.  There are two strong failure modes, the obvious one is when you set the property in the code that calls SerialPort.Write() **before** the response to the previous command is received.  Interlocking is required to prevent that from happening, you don't have any.  Works fine when you debug, not when you run your code at full speed.

The non-obvious failure mode is the e.EventType property in your DataReceived event handler.  You *must* check it to verify that your event handler got called for SerialData.Chars.  It will also fire for SerialData.Eof when you transfer binary data, you must ignore that one.

Interlocking requires at least an AutoResetEvent, call its Set() method in the event handler, you must call its WaitOne() method in the code that calls Write() so it cannot progress until the response was received.  You'll now run into another nasty problem, your Invoke() call will deadlock.  You'll need to fix that by calling BeginInvoke() instead and do so only after calling Read().  You must also pass a copy of the array so it cannot be altered when DataReceived continues firing.

This is all pretty hard to get right.  The core issue is that your receiving code cannot by itself figure out when a response was received in full.  That requires a *protocol*, enough information in the response bytes to allow the reader to figure out when the response is complete.  You might well be ahead by eliminating the DataReceived event completely and have the code that calls Write() also immediately call Read() to get the response.  This causes delays, but you already get those from the required WaitOne() call.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  We actually think need a DataReceived event because are requesting data to be sent to us and we are receiving multiple packets delayed by a specific interval from that one request command.  We are also having trouble understanding what the BeginInvoke() does and how to implement that.  Would you mind providing us with a structure of code to expand on what you mean?